# XSLT Prevent or Remove multiple References

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persons>
    <person id="1" type="parent">
        <name>father</name>
        <person-reference type="child">3</person-reference>
        <person-reference type="child">4</person-reference>
    </person>
    <person id="2" type="parent">
        <name>mother</name>
        <person-reference type="child">3</person-reference>
        <person-reference type="child">4</person-reference>
    </person>
    <person id="3">
        <name>brother</name>
    </person>
    <person id="4">
        <name>sister</name>
    </person>
</persons>
```

With the following XSLT transformation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/persons">
        <relations>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="person[@type = 'parent']"/>
        </relations>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="person">
        <parent>
            <name><xsl:value-of select="name"/></name>
        </parent>

        <xsl:apply-templates select="person-reference[@type = 'child']"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="person-reference">
        <child>
            <name><xsl:value-of select="//person[@id = current()]/name"/></name>
        </child>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I get this XML (Result):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<relations xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <parent>
        <name>father</name>
    </parent>
    <child>
        <name>brother</name>
    </child>
    <child>
        <name>sister</name>
    </child>
    <parent>
        <name>mother</name>
    </parent>
    <child>
        <name>brother</name>
    </child>
    <child>
        <name>sister</name>
    </child>
</relations>
```

But what I would like is this XML (Expected Result):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<relations xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <parent>
        <name>father</name>
    </parent>
    <child>
        <name>brother</name>
    </child>
    <child>
        <name>sister</name>
    </child>
    <parent>
        <name>mother</name>
    </parent>
</relations>
```

Or this (Optional Expected Result):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<relations xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <parent>
        <name>father</name>
    </parent>
    <parent>
        <name>mother</name>
    </parent>
    <child>
        <name>brother</name>
    </child>
    <child>
        <name>sister</name>
    </child>
</relations>
```

Is there are way with XSLT to prevent double output using references like I do?

Comment: I think you have to explain a little more here. Because your expected output could easily be generated by ignoring any person-reference and id, only by looking to type attribute of person. But this would most likely not help in the long term.

Comment: Good point. I have edited the example a bit. Expected output really needs to go through person-reference.

Comment: Denis, are you using an XSLT 2.0 processor (as you have used `version="2.0"` on your `xsl:stylesheet` element)? And can there be multiple levels of parent/child relationships?

Comment: Martin, yes XSLT 2.0 processor in the software. Although my IDE processor is XSLT 1.0 for simple testing. There are some nestings in the full XSLT, but fixed with the solution in mind. Thank you for your comment. It's funny how you guys can look in my mind :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent duplicated person-reference  (with xslt-1.0) you can use `xsl-key`.

```
<xsl:key name="kReference" match="person-reference"  use="."/>
```

And test if the current reference is the first one.

```
<xsl:if test=" generate-id()= generate-id( key( 'kReference', current()/text())[1] )" >
```

Therefor try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:key name="kReference" match="person-reference"  use="."/>

    <xsl:template match="/persons">
        <relations>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="person[@type = 'parent']"/>
        </relations>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="person">
        <parent>
            <name>
                <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
            </name>
        </parent>

        <xsl:apply-templates select="person-reference"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="person-reference">
        <xsl:if test=" generate-id()= generate-id( key( 'kReference', current()/text())[1] )" >
            <child>
                <name>
                    <xsl:value-of select="//person[@id = current()]/name"/>
                </name>
            </child>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But still I fear there are more behind this question.

Comment: You are right. There is more behind this question in the complete complicated XSLT. I did extract this part with a simple example and integrated your solutions. It did work. Thank you.